# Finding speed of an object on an inclined spring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, spring

question posed here: http://puu.sh/nV7rw/504a7be88a.jpg

method: Conservation of energy

$E_{{mech}_i} = E_{{mech}_f}$

$U_i + KE_i = U_f + KE_f$

$\frac{1}{2}{k}{x^2} + {mgh_i} + 0 = \frac{1}{2}{m}{v^2} + {mgh_f}$

I derived $mgh_i$ using basic trigonometry as $$m(g\sin\theta)((D+d)\sin\theta)$$ and likewise $$mgh_f = m(g\sin\theta)((D)\sin\theta)$$

I solved this equation at this point and got $v = 2.19\frac{m}{s}$ the answer in the book is $2.4\frac{m}{s}$

Comment: It appears that you have answered your own question, I suggest you either add the answer that worked as an answer to your own question (you can answer your own question on the site) or restate the question and ask why didn't the other method work.

Comment: ok i removed the second method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $sin(\theta) = \frac{h_{i}}{D+d} = \frac{h_{f}}{D}$ and $U_{g} = mgh$, it follows that there should be only *one* factor of $sin(\theta)$ in *equations 4 and 5* corresponding to the *initial and final* potential energy of the object. If you make those corrections, you should be arriving at correct value of velocity for part (a) of the problem.

Comment: I retried the problem just now and realized I had derived the acceleration as along the plane of the board and the height as the height of the triangle formed by the board and the angle $\theta$. I corrected this mistake and got the correct answer. Thank :)